# Rails Bootstrap accordion collapse isn't behaving as I expect

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Rails app and have been using Bootstrap 2.3.2. I recently decided it was time to upgrade to Bootstrap 3. After doing this, a collapsible pane that used to work correctly now behaves completely incorrectly in Safari, and sort of incorrectly in Chrome. I have updated the classes appropriately, and here's the code:

```
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">
        <div class="panel panel-default left-column-entry" id="new-student-widget">
          <div class="header panel-heading">
            <div class='header-content panel-title'>
              <a data-toggle="collapse" id="newStudentToggle" data-parent="#accordion2" data-target="#newStudent">
                New student
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="newStudent" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body"  id="newStudentInner">
              <%= render 'student_profiles/new_student' %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

When I use this code, in Safari the panel starts collapsed, and when I click the panel heading, instead of it smoothly animating to the open position, it (first) instantly appears with no animation, then animates closed, the animates open. In Chrome, clicking the heading simply causes it to materialize with no animation. So in Chrome, it's closer to the right thing, but it still is clearly not behaving quite correctly.

I don't think there's anything wrong with my code, because when I paste in the example code from the Bootstrap 3 documentation (which works correctly in the documentation, of course), it displays the same problems.

I'm assuming this is some sort of conflict with JQuery or JQuery UI both of which I'm using. I've seen the `.noConflict()` method, but unfortunately, I have no idea how this actually works, how to use it, or if this is even the thing that would resolve this issue. Any ideas on what could be the problem or how to fix it (especially if it is a conflict?).

**Update**

It was a conflict. But not with jQuery. Instead, because of my feeble understanding of the asset pipeline and how the bootstrap-sass gem works, I had two simultaneous versions of bootstrap running, both of which were, apparently, executing the same javascript for the collapse action.

Comment: How about a jsfiddle or a link?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reproduce this in jsfiddle.

Comment: Bootstrap requires jQuery, so it's not conflicting with jQuery. There have been reported conflicts with jQuery UI however.

Comment: If you can't repro in JS Fiddle, then that usually means the problem lies in your custom CSS or JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Because of my feeble understanding of the asset pipeline and how the bootstrap-sass gem works, I had two simultaneous versions (2.3.2 and 3.2.x) of bootstrap running, both of which were, apparently, executing the same javascript for the collapse action and tripping all over each other in the process.